# Imaging program that can duplicate active Intel RAID partitions

Tags: windows

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/715961/expand-intel-rapid-store-raid-5-to-raid-10

I have a RAID 5 volume that I want to convert to RAID 10. It's made up using the Intel Rapid Storage controller, on Windows Small Business Server 2011. There are 4 hard drives in there right now. My goal was to degrade the RAID 5 to only using 2 disks, set up the RAID 10 with two failed disks, image the data over, then destroy the rest of the RAID 5 and setup the RAID 10. Assuming this is possible, what software will allow me to image an Intel-based RAID hard drive set? I am OK with launching a LiveCD, but it must recognize the RAID set in order to work properly; free would be a great plus as well.